# Quartz Scheduler - Not running the task

Tags: scheduled-tasks, native, quartz-scheduler

I am working on scheduling the tasks using Quartz API. I tried scheduling notepad.exe and in the logs, I see the following line -
org.quartz.jobs.NativeJob runNativeCommand About to runcmd.exe /C c:/WINDOWS/notepad.exe ...

But the notepad is not coming up. Same is the issue with any exe or batch file.
I also see the notepad.exe as a running process in Task Manager.

Code:-

```
JobDataMap map = new JobDataMap();
map.put(NativeJob.PROP_COMMAND, "c:/WINDOWS/notepad.exe");
```

Comment: That's a damned peculiar use of Quartz... what are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: Since you can see in Task Manager, what user is notepad.exe running as?

Comment: I think the real question here is "how to run the job as a particular user?"

Comment: I changed the job to run under my user name, but no luck.